# JQuery UI stop drop from activating twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

We are trying to get a specific effect going with drag and drop.

As soon as the object that is being dragged is moved and option bar is suppose to move up from the bottom.  If you move the dragable item between columns it works fine.
But when you drop it on one of the options on the bottom bar, first the column drop goes off and then the drop for the option, we want only the option to go off. I've tried setting greed to true, but it's not helping.

Any ideas on what we should do will be great.

I prepared a JSFiddle example of the problem here
http://jsfiddle.net/rA4CB/65/

The Javascript code

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        cursor: "crosshair",
        revert: "invalid",
        start: function () {
            $('#toolbar').slideToggle({
                direction: "up"
            }, 300);
        },
        stop: function () {
            $('#toolbar').slideToggle({
                direction: "down"
            }, 300);
        }
    });

    $("#stage1").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("drop stage 1");
            $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            $(dropped).detach().css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }).appendTo(droppedOn);
        }
    });

    $("#stage2").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("drop stage 2");
            $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            $(dropped).detach().css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }).appendTo(droppedOn);
        }
    });

    $("#stage3").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("drop stage 3");
            $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            $(dropped).detach().css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }).appendTo(droppedOn);
        }
    });

    $("#DealLost").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        greedy:true,
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
           alert("Invalid "  + $(dropped).attr('id'));
           $(dropped).remove();
            $('#toolbar').slideToggle({
                direction: "down"
            }, 300);
        }
    });

    $("#DealWon").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        greedy:true,
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            alert("Valid " + $(dropped).attr('id'));
            $(dropped).remove();
            $('#toolbar').slideToggle({
                direction: "down"
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Regards
Francois

Comment: What browser are you using?  At least for me in the latest versions of Chrome,Filefox and IE10..  It seems to be working. If I drag to one of the options in the bottom bar only the drop on the option goes off.  I am not seeing an `drop stage` alert.

Comment: Hi Trevor 

Sorry I see now I did not make the column long enough they have to be behind the bar the moves up from below. See below

http://jsfiddle.net/rA4CB/66/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var dOTb = "false";
$("#stage1").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function (event, ui){
        if($(this).attr("Id") == "DealLost" || $(this).attr("id") == "DealWon")
        alert("drop stage 1");
        $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
```

The only method I can think of is doing a manual check on which droppable your draggable box is dragged  dropped on.[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Diegolar/2JCN4/)

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue we applied this line to each droppable function
if($(this).attr("Id") == "DealLost" || $(this).attr("id") == "DealWon")